# How filter Server names from application urls in grafana

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I'm using prometheus as a datasource and windows exporter as exporter on monitoring server. I've made a variable for server where i want to show server names only what should i write next to filter out server names and leave out applications url

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a metrics that only contain server names, then yes. For example if you have a metrics like:

- `host_cpu_number{instance="192.168.1.1"}`
- `host_cpu_number{instance="192.168.1.2"}`

then you can use `label_values(host_cpu_number, instance)` to get `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.2`